# Compiling POLE++ using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, visual-c++-2012

Unfortunately I didn't find my answer in questions with a similar name.

I'm trying to compile the [POLE++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polepp/files/polepp/) library along [boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries using Visual Studio 2012.
I have the following code: [filename: path.hpp from POLE++ library]

```
    #include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
    #include "pole/pole.h"
    .
    .
    .
    // iteration over the names in the path
            class iterator : public boost::iterator_facade< iterator, std::string const, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag >
            {
            .
            .
            .   
            private:
                .
                .
                .
                reference dereference() const { assert(m_pos < m_full_path.length()); return m_name; }
                bool equal( const iterator& rhs ) const;
                void increment();
                void decrement();

                static std::string first_name( const std::string& src );
                std::string             m_name;      // cache current 
                .
                .
                .
            };
```

And here are the errors I get:

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dereference'

Both erros point to the line that starts with `reference dereference() const ...`

How can I resolve the errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you need a boost version from 2007 since that is when the download was created.

Comment: @drescherjm You are right, I used an older version and now it works. Thank you.